Setting corners for panoramas using DJI RS Gimbal (e.g., RS 3 Mini)
I've been using a variety of motorised heads over many years for making panoramic images (see https://speleotrove.com/gallery/) currently up to JPEG limits.
Strangely these are all around 1.3-1.5kg which is about 50% more than my preferred 'lightweight' camera lens combination (Lumix G95 + 45-175mm PowerZoom).
I'm now looking at the DJI RS 3 Mini gimbal which, at 0.8kg, seems attractive.
Specifically, which lock(s) should be engaged when using the  RS 3 mini on a tripod for making high-resolution panoramas (similar to those at https://speleotrove.com/gallery/Kenilworth_Castle.html)?

Your question is open, forum type, which is not the way this site work: question + answer(s)

Hi Mike, welcome to Photo-SE. As written, your question is too open-ended, not specific enough. Stack Exchange sites are Q&A, not discussion forums. Please edit your post to ask a specific question. Thanks! =)

I just found this site .. there was nothing that I saw that suggested that questions had to be phrased in a certain way.  I apologise.  I  will edit my post to try and make it more specific .... but why are y'all so unfriendly to a newcomer?
